# How to check if a field is encryptable

Tags: apex, platform-encryption, shield

i  want something like a report for all my fields in the org if they are encrytable or not and i want to know if they are encrypted currently.

By the getDescribe method i can detect if a field is encrypted by the function isEncrypted or the boolean parameter encrypted.
But i want to know if the field is encrytable at all.

I have build a map based on Encrypt Standard Fields (seen here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_standard_fields.htm&type=5) and a set with encryptable date-types like given here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_custom_fields.htm&type=5

I ask if it is a standardfield and check in the map, else ask if the set contains the datatype of the datafield.

Problem is, i have to maintain it.

If i edit or create a field there is a checkbox if it is encryptable, if not there is not. Can i somehow else get the information in apex?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry this is something that we don't expose publicly today in the API.

What you have is very close to the truth, even though it's arguably hard to maintain

Comment: What do you mean by 'very close to the truth'? Am i missing something out?
What is the reason to not expose this public? And can we expect it to be public in the future?